# what is the correct use of connection to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Winforms program that connects to SQL Server 2008.

There are 100 users that connect to this database and

run search query --> and update the database.

I open the connection when the program starts and close when the program ends.

Is this the right thing to do ?

Is it better to open connection -> run query -> update -> and close connection ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it be better to open connection ->
>   run query -> update -> and close
>   connection ?

Yes, SQL Server already optimizes connections and [pooling is handled by ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). Open the connection use it to get what you want and then close it. Let SQL manage the rest.

From MSDN (source above):

> We strongly recommend that you always
>   close the connection when you are
>   finished using it so that the
>   connection will be returned to the
>   pool.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question and I believe it has been answered years before.

Always, start the connection -> run SQL -> Close.

Let the **connection pooling** worry about the cost of opening and closing connection. If you keep using the same connection string (achievable by using **Integrated Security**) you rarely open a new connection and resue existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a database connection open, you are keeping that much memory reserved for that task.  Therefore, the performance may be affected.  Plus, if there is a critical error in the program and it exits prematurely, that connection may not be automatically released.